# I am trying to create analytics country by Players completed the game , convert date to hours

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle-apex, analytics

This is the table sports table

```
Country Players Hours   Completed_Time
India   Player1 7       24-05-2021 07:29
India   Player2 7       24-05-2021 07:21
India   Player3 7       24-05-2021 07:26
India   Player4 7       24-05-2021 07:30
India   Player5 2       25-05-2021 02:01
  US    Player1 8       25-05-2021 08:54
  US    Player2 8       25-05-2021 08:57
  US    Player3 8       25-05-2021 08:54
  **US  Player4 8       25-05-2021 08:45
  US    Player5 05      26-05-2021 05:19**
```

while plotting chart I facing problem to convert `Completed Time` column that ***datetime*** into ***hours***

I have used below oracle SQL query

```
select Country,Players,TO_NUMBER(TO_CHAR(Completed_Time,'HH')) as Hours 
from  sports
```

only hours is not enough to plot the graph
since if we take only hours then in case

```
Country Players Hours    Completed_Time
  US    Player4 **8**   **25**-05-2021 **08**:45
  US    Player5 **05**  **26**-05-2021 **05**:19
```

Player5  took one day extra than Player4 so
in this case, I want +24 in hours value for Player5 ,Player4 hours should be **8** and for Player5 hours should be **29**

Comment: I'm not following , what's your desired output? but if I understand correctly , you have to have a startdate and calculate hours from that startdate for all the players

Comment: What is the start of the interval for each row?

Comment: start date is not there because of that i am facing problem, only Completed_Time is there

Comment: then what do you mean by "hour" , what does this column represent?

Answer (score 0):

if you don't have startdate , you can get hour difference by comapring to the first Completed_Time in your data :

```
select * , 24 * (Completed_Time - min(Completed_Time) over ()) as hourdiff
from sports
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you need time difference from the particular country start playing. Try out below query.

```
SELECT mq.Country,
         mq.Players,
         (24*(to_date(mq.Completed_Time,
         'DD-MM-YYYY HH') - to_date(sq.start_hr, 'DD-MM-YYYY')))+TO_NUMBER(TO_CHAR(mq.Completed_Time,'HH')) AS diff_hours
FROM sports AS mq
INNER JOIN 
    (SELECT Country ,
        TO_DATE(min(Completed_Time),
        'DD-MM-YYYY') AS start_hr
    FROM sports
    GROUP BY  Country) AS sq
    ON sq.Country = mq.Country;
```